# Difference between var a={ }; and var a= new functionObj();

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between

```
var a= { 
    grade: "A",
    price: 10
};
```

and

```
function functionObj(){
   this.grade="A";
   this.price=10;   
}
var a = new functionObj();
```

Comment: Yeah, top one is an error. That is the difference.

Comment: The first one points to a list if you correct the braces with square brackets.  The second one points to a function.  Chalk and cheese.

Comment: @duffymo -- Chalk and cheese...never heard that before.

Comment: I think you mean `grade:"A", price: 19` in the first one

Comment: Read: http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: you probably mean a={grade:"A",price:10} right?

Comment: Maybe you can check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 The first you define an object literal and the second you define a function that can be used as a template to create instances.

Comment: @Andy: *"In the first example a's constructor is `Object.prototype`"* No, its constructor is `Object`. Its *prototype* is assigned from `Object.prototype` (as of when it's constructed).

Comment: "Different as chalk and cheese".  If you change it to "cheese and cheesecake", it's a nice analogy for "java and javascript"

Answer (score 3):

Your first one is a one-off: It creates a single object that has nothing in common with other objects (except, of course, the things that **all** objects have in common).

Your second one uses a *constructor function*. One of the useful things about constructor functions is that they have an object that gets assigned to the objects constructed using them as the objects' *prototype*. This means that if you refer to a property on the object that it doesn't have its own copy of, the engine looks at the object's prototype to see if *it* has it. This is the basis of JavaScript's prototypical inheritance.

E.g., the second form lets you create several objects with shared characteristics via their shared prototype.

Concrete example:

```
function Circle(r) { // Constructor function names are initially capitalized by convention
    this.radius = r;
}
Circle.prototype.area = function() {
    return this.radius * this.radius * Math.PI;
};
Circle.prototype.circumference = function() {
    return this.radius * 2 * Math.PI;
};
Circle.prototype.name = "Circle";

var c1 = new Circle(10);
console.log(c1.name);   // "Circle"
console.log(c1.area()); // 314.1592653589793

var c2 = new Circle(5);
console.log(c2.name);   // "Circle"
console.log(c2.area()); // 78.53981633974483
```

There, the `c1` and `c2` objects *inherit* the properties `area` and `circumference` from their shared prototype. Each object we create like that gets its prototype when we do `new Circle`; the prototype that gets assigned to it is the object that `Circle.prototype` is pointing to when we do that. As you can see, the properties on the prototype can refer to anything, including functions.

You don't *have* to use constructor functions to use prototypes, not since ECMAScript 5th edition came out. You can assign a prototype *directly* via `Object.create`:

```
var circlePrototype = {
    area: function() {
        return this.radius * this.radius * Math.PI;
    },
    circumference: function() {
        return this.radius * 2 * Math.PI;
    },
    name: "Circle"
};

var c1 = Object.create(circlePrototype);
c1.radius = 10;
console.log(c1.name);   // "Circle"
console.log(c1.area()); // 314.1592653589793

var c2 = Object.create(circlePrototype);
c1.radius = 5;
console.log(c2.name);   // "Circle"
console.log(c2.area()); // 78.53981633974483
```

Constructor functions just keep all the pieces (the prototype and the initialization logic) in one tidy place. The downside to constructor functions is that they tend to push you toward a "class-like" way of looking at prototypical inheritance. Although class-like inheritance is useful and popular, it's not the only game in town. It's not uncommon to want to create an object that's a facade in front of another object somewhat ad-hoc: `Object.create` is great for that situation.